# iOS: Universal link always opens the app

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

The apple-app-site-associated JSON on the server looks like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": {
            "TEAM_AND_BUNDLE_ID": {
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the method `func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool` to be called so I can sort out whether the app should actually be opened (true for calling myurl.com/open, false for calling just myurl.com).

**But the appdelegate method is not called, the app is simply opened.**

The obious solution would be to put that path component into the JSON but as far as I know that JSON is only downloaded when the app is installed, so any changes in the JSON are not taken into account.

Comment: I've made a guide with useful information. https://github.com/NikKovIos/AASA-Universal-Links-Information/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is correct behavior**. Your app will *always* launch if a URL meeting the criteria in the `apple-app-site-association` file is tapped. There's no way you can control that within `continue userActivity`.

You are correct that the `apple-app-site-association` file is downloaded when the app is installed. It will be re-downloaded for updates through the App Store, which means to add new paths and ensure all users have them, you generally need to release an app update.

The correct way to exclude the root path of the site is by formatting your `apple-app-site-association` file as follows:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": {
            "TEAM_AND_BUNDLE_ID": {
                "paths": [
                    "NOT /",
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `/` matches only the root of the site, and the `*` matches the *entire* site (including the root). This works because iOS evaluates the rules in order and will stop once it finds a match.

An even better way to handle this without needing to constantly update your app is by using a hosted deep link service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links.